# Synchronise two selectizeInputs when filtering two attributes of a data frame (mulitple selection)

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

In my shinydashboard app I want to give the user the option to filter a data frame by alternative attributes. My data frame has an "ID" column and a "Name" column in a 1:1 relation. With two selectizeInputs the user can filter eather by the one or the other.

What I want achieve now is updating the other selectizeInput when selecting items in one of them. So both selectizeInputs show the corresponding items of the data frame. I managed to solve this, as long as I restrict the selection to a single item, but not with a multiple selection.

The following minimum code is the closest I could get so far, but it does not allow multiple selection. Obviousely due to a kind of deadlock situation where the first item selected causes the other seletizeInput to filter the same element which automatically updates the first selectizeInput again to this single item.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = 'Test alternative select') ,
  
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
              selectizeInput(inputId = 'id' ,
                             label = 'ID' ,
                             choices = NULL ,
                             selected = NULL ,
                             multiple = TRUE ,
                             options = list(plugins = list('remove_button'))) ,
              selectizeInput(inputId = 'name' ,
                             label = 'Name' ,
                             choices = NULL ,
                             selected = NULL ,
                             multiple = TRUE ,
                             options = list(plugins = list('remove_button')))
        ))) ,
  
  dashboardBody()
)
  
  server <- function(input, output , session) {
    
    data <- tribble(
      ~ID , ~Name ,
      '1' , 'France' ,
      '2' , 'Italy' ,
      '3' , 'Germany' ,
      '4' , 'Spain' ,
      '5' , 'Portugal'
    )
    
    observe({
      if (is.null(input$id)) {
        updateSelectizeInput(session = session ,
                             inputId = 'name' ,
                             choices = data$Name ,
                             options = list(plugins= list('remove_button')))
      } else {
        choices <- data %>%
          filter(ID %in% input$id) %>%
          pull(Name)
        
        updateSelectizeInput(session = session ,
                             inputId = 'name' ,
                             choices = choices ,
                             selected = choices ,
                             options = list(plugins= list('remove_button')))
      }
    })
    
    observe({
      if (is.null(input$name)) {
        updateSelectizeInput(session = session ,
                             inputId = 'id' ,
                             choices = data$ID ,
                             options = list(plugins= list('remove_button')))
      } else {
        choices <- data %>%
          filter(Name %in% input$name) %>%
          pull(ID)
        
        updateSelectizeInput(session = session ,
                             inputId = 'id' ,
                             choices = choices ,
                             selected = choices ,
                             options = list(plugins= list('remove_button')))
      }
    })
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I'm not sure if this can be solved this way at all, but if "yes", I probably have to use "isolate" somehow. But I can't figure it out.

Comment: I think what you're looking for here is not `isolate` but [`freezeReactiveValues()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/shiny/man/freezeReactiveValue.html).
It's usage is very well described in the book [Mastering Shiny](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-dynamic.html#freezing-reactive-inputs), and the main idea is _"You might wonder when you should use freezeReactiveValue(): it’s actually good practice to always use it when you dynamically change an input value"_.
Let us know if you manage to make it work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this

```
server <- function(input, output , session) {
  data <- tribble(
    ~ID , ~Name ,
    '1' , 'France' ,
    '2' , 'Italy' ,
    '3' , 'Germany' ,
    '4' , 'Spain' ,
    '5' , 'Portugal'
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$id, {
    if (is.null(input$id)) {
      updateSelectizeInput(session , 'name' , choices = data$Name , selected = NULL)
    } else{
      sel <- data %>% filter(ID %in% input$id) %>% pull('Name')
      updateSelectizeInput(session , 'name' , selected = isolate(sel))
    }
    print(input$id)
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input$name, {
    if (is.null(input$name)) {
      updateSelectizeInput(session , 'id' , choices = data$ID , selected = NULL)
    } else {
      sel <- data %>% filter(Name %in% input$name) %>% pull('ID')
      updateSelectizeInput(session , 'id' , selected =isolate(sel))
    }
    
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some try and errors I found a solution with the following changes to my code. Essentially I used observeEvent instead of observe.

I tried the hint from kenshuri with `freezeReactiveValue()`(thanks for that), but it didn't help or made it even worse.

The following solution does, what I want to achieve. Only remainig issue:
when deleting all items in one box the last one remains in the other box. But I can live with that.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = 'Test alternative select') ,
  
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        selectizeInput(inputId = 'id' ,
                       label = 'ID' ,
                       choices = NULL ,
                       selected = NULL ,
                       multiple = TRUE ,
                       options = list(plugins = list('remove_button'))) ,
        selectizeInput(inputId = 'name' ,
                       label = 'Name' ,
                       choices = NULL ,
                       selected = NULL ,
                       multiple = TRUE ,
                       options = list(plugins = list('remove_button')))
      ))) ,
  
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output , session) {
  data <- tribble(
    ~ID , ~Name ,
    '1' , 'France' ,
    '2' , 'Italy' ,
    '3' , 'Germany' ,
    '4' , 'Spain' ,
    '5' , 'Portugal'
  )
  
  observe({
    if (is.null(input$id) & is.null(input$name)) {
      updateSelectizeInput(session , 'name' , choices = data$Name , selected = NULL)
      
      updateSelectizeInput(session , 'id' , choices = data$ID , selected = NULL)
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$id, {
      sel <- data %>% filter(ID %in% input$id) %>% pull('Name')
      updateSelectizeInput(session , 'name' , selected = isolate(sel))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$name, {
      sel <- data %>% filter(Name %in% input$name) %>% pull('ID')
      updateSelectizeInput(session , 'id' , selected =isolate(sel))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```